# Is this possible with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm parsing a file where I want to extract a certain string.

The string will be preceeded by some length of white space, followed by either:

- an H followed by 8 hex numbers

or

- a G followed by 9 hex numbers

followed by a carriage return and newline.

Is it possible for me to make an expression that is equivalent to "if the character is H, then  skip 8 characters, else if the character is a G then skip 9 characters" or even more simply "if the character is an H, skip 8 characters, else skip 9 characters".

The current regex I have that works well with H is **@"\s+H.{8}(?`<user>`.*)\r\n"**, but I'm stumped when it comes to adding conditional character counts. For instance, it'd be really nice if there were some syntax like [H|G].{8|9}, but I don't think this actually exists in regex syntax.

Comment: Rather than vaguely describing the input, you should provide examples to more clearly describe your scenario. Be specific in showing what input should result in what output. Regex is VERY particular, you're not going to get a good answer with this vague of a description.

Comment: honestly it's not the hardest thing to envision, it's a bunch of spaces, followed by H or G, followed by 8 or 9 hex characters, followed by a username, followed by \r\n, e.g. "             H0000003eMyUser\r\n" or "         G000000098MyOtherUser\r\n"

Comment: Could you not simply do:
@"\s+((H.{8})|(G.{9}))(?<user>.*)\r\n"?

Comment: that looks like it could work nicely, let me try it real quick. EDIT: it worked, great!

Comment: Yes. Definitely possible.  Give sample input and desired output

Comment: @Sean I'm just saying it would be a lot easier if you just SHOWED an example rather than making me construct an example (and maybe get it wrong) based on a description.

Comment: @Sean if it's easy to envision, then it should be easy for you to provide examples so someone can help you with your code. Examples should be included in the question as hunting through comments for additional information about the question is less than ideal.

Comment: @T.Kiley That isn't QUITE it. You still need to account for 9 hex following the H as well as 8 hex following the G. EDIT: Confused now. That would be correct based off the question, but OP later states in comment `H or G, followed by 8 or 9` which is conflicting. Thats why you should provide examples!!!

Comment: @tnw no, read the bullet points (which were very nicely edited in by Scott Mermelstein, thanks Scott!) EDIT: the comment was in remark to you saying how confusing the question was, but really I doubt you even read it before stating how confusing it was. Would it be better if in the future I ask a question of the form: "here's my input ... here's the desired output ... now give me the answer!"?

Comment: @tnw Nicely underlying your point about examples! :P

Comment: @Sean O_O are you seriously going to debate whether or not examples in a regex question are a good idea? There simply isn't an argument, quite clearly demonstrated by my earlier comment. There's much less ambiguity with examples.

Comment: I just don't see how the question was vague, it was pretty clearly stated. Tell me which part was at all "vague"?

Comment: @T.Kiley make an answer from your comment so I can accept it, please

Comment: @Sean Oh, I just saw your earlier edit wildly accusing me of not reading the question... YOU asked the question to invite feedback, if you're going to take it personally and instead attack the people trying to help, don't bother asking. I wouldn't have commented if I hadn't read it, but I see you're clearly not interested in a constructive discussion. Good luck

Comment: Funnily enough, your question wasn't vague until I asked you to clarify: `H or G, followed by 8 or 9` is different from what your question asked. Nice! If you had simply provided examples to begin with, we wouldn't be having this discussion.

Comment: I assumed you read the question and would have known H or G, followed by 8 or 9, RESPECTIVELY. But whatever, internet arguments never end well, so let's just let it go. I'll just say that I can see your point of view that not everybody may be able to envision things as well as I'd expect them to, so examples may be helpful in future posts, no matter how obvious I think the question is (because ultimately it's the other SO members who need to understand it, not me).

Comment: It sounds possible. Give me some sample input and expected output I'll get back soon.

Comment: Thank you for challenging question. Check out my solution.

Comment: @Sean done, but some of the other answers are more accurate -- if you are only matching hex you probably don't want to match `.{8}`

Comment: @T.Kiley good point except that I know the characters themselves don't matter and will be disregarded, they'll just happen to be hex characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment, I just elaborated on yours to get

```
\s+((H.{8})|(G.{9}))(?<user>.*)\r\n
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/rjSvUSxyIWikW09O)

Since Regex corresponds to Finte State Automata, it is easy to see why this is trivial, on reading an H we go in to one state, G in to the other.

Comment: Overuses parentheses just a bit (the two alternatives don't really need them), but +1 for the diagram.

Comment: I prefer the clarity of too many brackets and yeah, https://www.debuggex.com/ is absolutely awesome, real time, embeddable, finite state machines for regular expressions!

Comment: Ya but is the javascript regex parser the same as .Net? I believe they are quite different. Debuggex does not do .Net. Or am I missing something....

Comment: nice diagram, what'd you use to make it?

Comment: @omegaman regular expressions are regular expressions not too hard to convert between the language nuances. That said, didn't know they were different so maybe one day it'll catch me out, but useful for getting the body down (if not advanced stuff like look ahead and groups)

Comment: @T.Kiley Your pattern does work and frankly is the simplest (not a knock) and best for the situation. There are language differences and underneath the covers the engines on *how they do the matching* is different. Regardless knowing both is actually a good task to do. :-)

Comment: @OmegaMan: Most RE languages these days have nearly identical syntax for the features they support, though.  The only thing that'll really cause compatibility issues here is the `(?<user>)`; there are two common syntaxes for named groups, and some RE engines don't support them at all yet.  (JavaScript and POSIX don't.  PCRE, on the other hand, apparently supports both common syntaxes.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use:

```
\s+(?:H[a-fA-F0-9]{8}|G[a-fA-F0-9]{9})(?<user>.*)\r\n
```

Comment: Why have an anchor at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 1):

Well it is possible with `Regex`. You can use conditions in regex.

Here is the main part of "Regex" you're struggling with. I assume you could build with this.

```
var subject = "H12345678ABC";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?((?<hgroup>H))\k<hgroup>.{8}|.{10})(?<user>.*)");
var match =regex.Match(subject);
if(match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["user"].Value);//prints ABC
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No Match");
}
```

Break up:

```
(?<hgroup>H)    Matches H and stores in group hgroup
\k<hgroup>.{8}  If true checks matches H followed by any 8 characters
.{10}           If not then match next 10 characters(G followed by 9 other characters)
(?<user>.*)     Captures rest all to user group
```

Here is a working [Demo](http://ideone.com/LX7JRI)

Answer (score 0):

This does two if conditions. Use Regex option IgnorePatternWhitespace to allow commenting

```
(?(H0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]{6}[^\r\n\d]+)     # If an H with 8 hex digits is found
     H.{8}(?<User>[^\r\n\d]+)          # Then match the H user
    |                                  # else
    (?(G0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]{7}[^\r\n\d]+) # If G with 9 hex is found
      G.{9}(?<User>[^\r\n\d]+))        # Then match the G User
 )
```

---

### Update

The Achilles heal is that it is unclear what a username consists of...if the username has a digit say `1OmegaMan`...this will fail. But the OP has not specified that rule, nor given any *clear* examples.

So the assumption here is that a username is all alphabetic characters.

A better pattern to search for might be `H\d{8}[A-Z][^\r\n]+` which says that at least one alphabetic character is present after the digits which delineates the username from the digits.

Comment: `\d{8}` will match 8 *decimal* digits.  Question says they are hex.

Comment: I'm thinking the `0x` isn't part of the number.  (That is, the 8-9 digits are real digits.)  But since the OP didn't provide examples...i can't be too nitpicky about that.  :P

Comment: @cHao I wondered that myself as my answer goes down into 0 userful points and I get the `Unsung Hero` badge. *sigh*